# How to solve this 'SendMail Mail Relay Vulnerability'

Tags: security, smtp, openvas, crlf-vulnerability

I have used [openvas](http://www.openvas.org/) to scan vulnerabilities in my server.
I got this `SendMail Mail Relay Vulnerability`. But don't know how to resolve this.

Could you please give an hint to resolve this.

Comment: I have scanned for Linux server

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I will follow your instructions.